# Arduino Converting Decimal to Binary to Decimal

Tags: c, arduino, binary, decimal, pow

First off, I'm very new to the Arduino world. I think my code is fairly simple though, but yet it doesn't work.

So I'm making a script for my own knowledge converting decimal values to 8-bit binary values. So only 0 to 255 decimal to binary and then for checking converting it back to decimal.

Now I'm very confused why my code looks like it's working but only until three!

If anyone could help on this matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=0;i<=255;i++) {
    Serial.print("DecToBin: ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    boolean Bin[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    convertDecToBin(i,Bin);
    for(int j = 0;j<8;j++)
      Serial.print(Bin[j]);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    Serial.print(convertBinToDec(Bin));
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
  delay(1000000);
  // Very long delay to emulate only one "Execution" of the loop()
}

/*
The following function convert any int from 0-255 to binary.
You need to pass the int as agrument.
You also need to pass the 8bit array of boolean
*/
void convertDecToBin(int Dec, boolean Bin[]) {
  for(int i = 7 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if(pow(2, i)<=Dec) {
      Dec = Dec - pow(2, i);
      Bin[8-(i+1)] = 1;
    } else {
    }
  }
}

/*
This following function will convert any 8 bit array of boolean to a Decimal number.
you need to pass an boolean array of 8 bits
function return a int
*/
int convertBinToDec(boolean Bin[]) {
  int ReturnInt = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i<8;i++) {
    if(Bin[7-i]) {
      Serial.print("2^");
      Serial.print(i);
      ReturnInt = ReturnInt + (int)pow(2, i);
      Serial.print("=");
      Serial.print((int)pow(2, i));
      Serial.print("+");
    }
  }
  Serial.print(",");
  return ReturnInt;
}
```

Now pay attention to the `3` value. That's where it starts being offset. To my knowledge everything is correct. Can anyone spot the mistake?

```
DecToBin: 0 -> 00000000 -> ,0
DecToBin: 1 -> 00000001 -> 2^0=1+,1
DecToBin: 2 -> 00000010 -> 2^1=2+,2
DecToBin: 3 -> 00000011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+,3
DecToBin: 4 -> 00000100 -> 2^2=3+,3
DecToBin: 5 -> 00000101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+,4
DecToBin: 6 -> 00000110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+,5
DecToBin: 7 -> 00000111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+,6
DecToBin: 8 -> 00001000 -> 2^3=7+,7
DecToBin: 9 -> 00001001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+,8
DecToBin: 10 -> 00001010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+,9
DecToBin: 11 -> 00001011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+,10
DecToBin: 12 -> 00001100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+,10
DecToBin: 13 -> 00001101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+,11
DecToBin: 14 -> 00001110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+,12
DecToBin: 15 -> 00001111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+,13
DecToBin: 16 -> 00010000 -> 2^4=15+,15
DecToBin: 17 -> 00010001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+,16
DecToBin: 18 -> 00010010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+,17
DecToBin: 19 -> 00010011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+,18
DecToBin: 20 -> 00010100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+,18
DecToBin: 21 -> 00010101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+,19
DecToBin: 22 -> 00010110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+,20
DecToBin: 23 -> 00010111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+,21
DecToBin: 24 -> 00011000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+,22
DecToBin: 25 -> 00011001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+,23
DecToBin: 26 -> 00011010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+,24
DecToBin: 27 -> 00011011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+,25
DecToBin: 28 -> 00011100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+,25
DecToBin: 29 -> 00011101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+,26
DecToBin: 30 -> 00011110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+,27
DecToBin: 31 -> 00011111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+,28
DecToBin: 32 -> 00100000 -> 2^5=31+,31
DecToBin: 33 -> 00100001 -> 2^0=1+2^5=31+,32
DecToBin: 34 -> 00100010 -> 2^1=2+2^5=31+,33
DecToBin: 35 -> 00100011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^5=31+,34
DecToBin: 36 -> 00100100 -> 2^2=3+2^5=31+,34
DecToBin: 37 -> 00100101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^5=31+,35
DecToBin: 38 -> 00100110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+,36
DecToBin: 39 -> 00100111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+,37
DecToBin: 40 -> 00101000 -> 2^3=7+2^5=31+,38
DecToBin: 41 -> 00101001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^5=31+,39
DecToBin: 42 -> 00101010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+,40
DecToBin: 43 -> 00101011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+,41
DecToBin: 44 -> 00101100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+,41
DecToBin: 45 -> 00101101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+,42
DecToBin: 46 -> 00101110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+,43
DecToBin: 47 -> 00101111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+,44
DecToBin: 48 -> 00110000 -> 2^4=15+2^5=31+,46
DecToBin: 49 -> 00110001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^5=31+,47
DecToBin: 50 -> 00110010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+,48
DecToBin: 51 -> 00110011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+,49
DecToBin: 52 -> 00110100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+,49
DecToBin: 53 -> 00110101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+,50
DecToBin: 54 -> 00110110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+,51
DecToBin: 55 -> 00110111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+,52
DecToBin: 56 -> 00111000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,53
DecToBin: 57 -> 00111001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,54
DecToBin: 58 -> 00111010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,55
DecToBin: 59 -> 00111011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,56
DecToBin: 60 -> 00111100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,56
DecToBin: 61 -> 00111101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,57
DecToBin: 62 -> 00111110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,58
DecToBin: 63 -> 00111111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+,59
DecToBin: 64 -> 01000000 -> 2^6=63+,63
DecToBin: 65 -> 01000001 -> 2^0=1+2^6=63+,64
DecToBin: 66 -> 01000010 -> 2^1=2+2^6=63+,65
DecToBin: 67 -> 01000011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^6=63+,66
DecToBin: 68 -> 01000100 -> 2^2=3+2^6=63+,66
DecToBin: 69 -> 01000101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^6=63+,67
DecToBin: 70 -> 01000110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^6=63+,68
DecToBin: 71 -> 01000111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^6=63+,69
DecToBin: 72 -> 01001000 -> 2^3=7+2^6=63+,70
DecToBin: 73 -> 01001001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^6=63+,71
DecToBin: 74 -> 01001010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^6=63+,72
DecToBin: 75 -> 01001011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^6=63+,73
DecToBin: 76 -> 01001100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+,73
DecToBin: 77 -> 01001101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+,74
DecToBin: 78 -> 01001110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+,75
DecToBin: 79 -> 01001111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+,76
DecToBin: 80 -> 01010000 -> 2^4=15+2^6=63+,78
DecToBin: 81 -> 01010001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^6=63+,79
DecToBin: 82 -> 01010010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^6=63+,80
DecToBin: 83 -> 01010011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^6=63+,81
DecToBin: 84 -> 01010100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+,81
DecToBin: 85 -> 01010101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+,82
DecToBin: 86 -> 01010110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+,83
DecToBin: 87 -> 01010111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+,84
DecToBin: 88 -> 01011000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,85
DecToBin: 89 -> 01011001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,86
DecToBin: 90 -> 01011010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,87
DecToBin: 91 -> 01011011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,88
DecToBin: 92 -> 01011100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,88
DecToBin: 93 -> 01011101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,89
DecToBin: 94 -> 01011110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,90
DecToBin: 95 -> 01011111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+,91
DecToBin: 96 -> 01100000 -> 2^5=31+2^6=63+,94
DecToBin: 97 -> 01100001 -> 2^0=1+2^5=31+2^6=63+,95
DecToBin: 98 -> 01100010 -> 2^1=2+2^5=31+2^6=63+,96
DecToBin: 99 -> 01100011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^5=31+2^6=63+,97
DecToBin: 100 -> 01100100 -> 2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+,97
DecToBin: 101 -> 01100101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+,98
DecToBin: 102 -> 01100110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+,99
DecToBin: 103 -> 01100111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+,100
DecToBin: 104 -> 01101000 -> 2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,101
DecToBin: 105 -> 01101001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,102
DecToBin: 106 -> 01101010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,103
DecToBin: 107 -> 01101011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,104
DecToBin: 108 -> 01101100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,104
DecToBin: 109 -> 01101101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,105
DecToBin: 110 -> 01101110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,106
DecToBin: 111 -> 01101111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+,107
DecToBin: 112 -> 01110000 -> 2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,109
DecToBin: 113 -> 01110001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,110
DecToBin: 114 -> 01110010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,111
DecToBin: 115 -> 01110011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,112
DecToBin: 116 -> 01110100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,112
DecToBin: 117 -> 01110101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,113
DecToBin: 118 -> 01110110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,114
DecToBin: 119 -> 01110111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,115
DecToBin: 120 -> 01111000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,116
DecToBin: 121 -> 01111001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,117
DecToBin: 122 -> 01111010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,118
DecToBin: 123 -> 01111011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,119
DecToBin: 124 -> 01111100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,119
DecToBin: 125 -> 01111101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,120
DecToBin: 126 -> 01111110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,121
DecToBin: 127 -> 01111111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+,122
DecToBin: 128 -> 10000000 -> 2^7=127+,127
DecToBin: 129 -> 10000001 -> 2^0=1+2^7=127+,128
DecToBin: 130 -> 10000010 -> 2^1=2+2^7=127+,129
DecToBin: 131 -> 10000011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^7=127+,130
DecToBin: 132 -> 10000100 -> 2^2=3+2^7=127+,130
DecToBin: 133 -> 10000101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^7=127+,131
DecToBin: 134 -> 10000110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^7=127+,132
DecToBin: 135 -> 10000111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^7=127+,133
DecToBin: 136 -> 10001000 -> 2^3=7+2^7=127+,134
DecToBin: 137 -> 10001001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^7=127+,135
DecToBin: 138 -> 10001010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^7=127+,136
DecToBin: 139 -> 10001011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^7=127+,137
DecToBin: 140 -> 10001100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^7=127+,137
DecToBin: 141 -> 10001101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^7=127+,138
DecToBin: 142 -> 10001110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^7=127+,139
DecToBin: 143 -> 10001111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^7=127+,140
DecToBin: 144 -> 10010000 -> 2^4=15+2^7=127+,142
DecToBin: 145 -> 10010001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^7=127+,143
DecToBin: 146 -> 10010010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^7=127+,144
DecToBin: 147 -> 10010011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^7=127+,145
DecToBin: 148 -> 10010100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^7=127+,145
DecToBin: 149 -> 10010101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^7=127+,146
DecToBin: 150 -> 10010110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^7=127+,147
DecToBin: 151 -> 10010111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^7=127+,148
DecToBin: 152 -> 10011000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,149
DecToBin: 153 -> 10011001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,150
DecToBin: 154 -> 10011010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,151
DecToBin: 155 -> 10011011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,152
DecToBin: 156 -> 10011100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,152
DecToBin: 157 -> 10011101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,153
DecToBin: 158 -> 10011110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,154
DecToBin: 159 -> 10011111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^7=127+,155
DecToBin: 160 -> 10100000 -> 2^5=31+2^7=127+,158
DecToBin: 161 -> 10100001 -> 2^0=1+2^5=31+2^7=127+,159
DecToBin: 162 -> 10100010 -> 2^1=2+2^5=31+2^7=127+,160
DecToBin: 163 -> 10100011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^5=31+2^7=127+,161
DecToBin: 164 -> 10100100 -> 2^2=3+2^5=31+2^7=127+,161
DecToBin: 165 -> 10100101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^7=127+,162
DecToBin: 166 -> 10100110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^7=127+,163
DecToBin: 167 -> 10100111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^7=127+,164
DecToBin: 168 -> 10101000 -> 2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,165
DecToBin: 169 -> 10101001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,166
DecToBin: 170 -> 10101010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,167
DecToBin: 171 -> 10101011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,168
DecToBin: 172 -> 10101100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,168
DecToBin: 173 -> 10101101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,169
DecToBin: 174 -> 10101110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,170
DecToBin: 175 -> 10101111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^7=127+,171
DecToBin: 176 -> 10110000 -> 2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,173
DecToBin: 177 -> 10110001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,174
DecToBin: 178 -> 10110010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,175
DecToBin: 179 -> 10110011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,176
DecToBin: 180 -> 10110100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,176
DecToBin: 181 -> 10110101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,177
DecToBin: 182 -> 10110110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,178
DecToBin: 183 -> 10110111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,179
DecToBin: 184 -> 10111000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,180
DecToBin: 185 -> 10111001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,181
DecToBin: 186 -> 10111010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,182
DecToBin: 187 -> 10111011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,183
DecToBin: 188 -> 10111100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,183
DecToBin: 189 -> 10111101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,184
DecToBin: 190 -> 10111110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,185
DecToBin: 191 -> 10111111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^7=127+,186
DecToBin: 192 -> 11000000 -> 2^6=63+2^7=127+,190
DecToBin: 193 -> 11000001 -> 2^0=1+2^6=63+2^7=127+,191
DecToBin: 194 -> 11000010 -> 2^1=2+2^6=63+2^7=127+,192
DecToBin: 195 -> 11000011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^6=63+2^7=127+,193
DecToBin: 196 -> 11000100 -> 2^2=3+2^6=63+2^7=127+,193
DecToBin: 197 -> 11000101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^6=63+2^7=127+,194
DecToBin: 198 -> 11000110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^6=63+2^7=127+,195
DecToBin: 199 -> 11000111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^6=63+2^7=127+,196
DecToBin: 200 -> 11001000 -> 2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,197
DecToBin: 201 -> 11001001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,198
DecToBin: 202 -> 11001010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,199
DecToBin: 203 -> 11001011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,200
DecToBin: 204 -> 11001100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,200
DecToBin: 205 -> 11001101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,201
DecToBin: 206 -> 11001110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,202
DecToBin: 207 -> 11001111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^6=63+2^7=127+,203
DecToBin: 208 -> 11010000 -> 2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,205
DecToBin: 209 -> 11010001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,206
DecToBin: 210 -> 11010010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,207
DecToBin: 211 -> 11010011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,208
DecToBin: 212 -> 11010100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,208
DecToBin: 213 -> 11010101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,209
DecToBin: 214 -> 11010110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,210
DecToBin: 215 -> 11010111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,211
DecToBin: 216 -> 11011000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,212
DecToBin: 217 -> 11011001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,213
DecToBin: 218 -> 11011010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,214
DecToBin: 219 -> 11011011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,215
DecToBin: 220 -> 11011100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,215
DecToBin: 221 -> 11011101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,216
DecToBin: 222 -> 11011110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,217
DecToBin: 223 -> 11011111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^6=63+2^7=127+,218
DecToBin: 224 -> 11100000 -> 2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,221
DecToBin: 225 -> 11100001 -> 2^0=1+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,222
DecToBin: 226 -> 11100010 -> 2^1=2+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,223
DecToBin: 227 -> 11100011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,224
DecToBin: 228 -> 11100100 -> 2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,224
DecToBin: 229 -> 11100101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,225
DecToBin: 230 -> 11100110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,226
DecToBin: 231 -> 11100111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,227
DecToBin: 232 -> 11101000 -> 2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,228
DecToBin: 233 -> 11101001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,229
DecToBin: 234 -> 11101010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,230
DecToBin: 235 -> 11101011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,231
DecToBin: 236 -> 11101100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,231
DecToBin: 237 -> 11101101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,232
DecToBin: 238 -> 11101110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,233
DecToBin: 239 -> 11101111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,234
DecToBin: 240 -> 11110000 -> 2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,236
DecToBin: 241 -> 11110001 -> 2^0=1+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,237
DecToBin: 242 -> 11110010 -> 2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,238
DecToBin: 243 -> 11110011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,239
DecToBin: 244 -> 11110100 -> 2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,239
DecToBin: 245 -> 11110101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,240
DecToBin: 246 -> 11110110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,241
DecToBin: 247 -> 11110111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,242
DecToBin: 248 -> 11111000 -> 2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,243
DecToBin: 249 -> 11111001 -> 2^0=1+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,244
DecToBin: 250 -> 11111010 -> 2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,245
DecToBin: 251 -> 11111011 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,246
DecToBin: 252 -> 11111100 -> 2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,246
DecToBin: 253 -> 11111101 -> 2^0=1+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,247
DecToBin: 254 -> 11111110 -> 2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,248
DecToBin: 255 -> 11111111 -> 2^0=1+2^1=2+2^2=3+2^3=7+2^4=15+2^5=31+2^6=63+2^7=127+,249
```

Comment: Don't use floating point math for simple integer operations which have exact integer results. Instead of `pow(2, i)` use `(1 << i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are going through an array 0-7 of 1s, you should be using bit shifting:

```
int convertBinToDec(boolean Bin[]) {
  int ReturnInt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (Bin[7 - i]) {
      Serial.print("Set Bit ");
      Serial.print(i);
      ReturnInt += 1<<i;
      Serial.print(" ==> ");
      Serial.print(1<<i);
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
  }
  return ReturnInt;
}

DecToBin: 1 -> 00000001 -> Set Bit 0 ==> 1, 1
DecToBin: 2 -> 00000010 -> Set Bit 1 ==> 1, 2
DecToBin: 3 -> 00000011 -> Set Bit 0 ==> 1, Set Bit 1 ==> 1, 3
DecToBin: 4 -> 00000100 -> Set Bit 2 ==> 2, 4
DecToBin: 5 -> 00000101 -> Set Bit 0 ==> 1, Set Bit 2 ==> 2, 5
DecToBin: 6 -> 00000110 -> Set Bit 1 ==> 1, Set Bit 2 ==> 2, 6
DecToBin: 7 -> 00000111 -> Set Bit 0 ==> 1, Set Bit 1 ==> 1, Set Bit 2 ==> 2, 7
DecToBin: 8 -> 00001000 -> Set Bit 3 ==> 4, 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!. It works! I don't understand bit shifting yet, But il research about it.
But I am still very confused on why the code didn't work at first with pow.

Comment: It might be slightly faster to change the `+=` to `|=`, given that it's just setting the bit.  I'm not sure - I'll read the datasheet.

Comment: Never mind, they both take one cycle: [from here, page 616](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)

Comment: zbw thanks for the research. I hesitated between += and |= but considering the entry-level of the question I didn't want to muddle the waters more :-)

Answer (score 1):

pow() gives the output in double. Do as Paul suggested.

You can also try including math.h if arduino has it and then using int(ceil(pow(int a, int b))) to get the exact value. As far as I can see.. pow() is giving output in double maybe like 3.999 something and int by default is doing flooring in it... so it converts to 3. ceil() takes it to the next largest int value. It may work.

Comment: Technically all the calculation I was making though pow should be giving hole numbers
I verified and all returned value from pow were all .00